# Add metadata to S3 objects pushed by Kinesis Firehose

Tags: metadata, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have Firehose stream pushing data to s3 with a small lambda processing the format.
I'd like these objects in S3 to have some metadata when created.

I find you can add it when using aws cli, or through the console, but I don't find a way to automate it for the files created from firehose.
Format from lambda only includes recordId, data and result.

Am I missing something? Or is this something I cannot customise with Firehose?

Thanks :)

Comment: I am looking for the same . Did you got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Firehose doesn't give that option out of box. But you can trigger an event notification when Firehose publishes a new object to S3. The event notification can trigger a lambda which will add the metadata.